# Create Object into Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the follow code and I want to achive the same result inside a for loop.

Is there a way to make it?

```
function makeNode(){
    let node = {value: 0, next :{} };
    let randon_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 -1)) + 1;
    node.value = randon_number;
    node.next = {};
    return node;
}   
function nodeList (){
    let node = makeNode();
    node.next = makeNode();
    node.next.next = makeNode();
    node.next.next.next = makeNode();
    node.next.next.next.next = makeNode();
    return node;
}
```

Output:

`{"value":45,"next":{"value":32,"next":{"value":52,"next":{"value":89,"next":{"value":32,"next":{}}}}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `for` loop

```js
function makeNode() {
  return {
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1,
    next: {}
  };
}

function makeNodeList(length) {
  let nodeList = makeNode()
  let currentNode = nodeList
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    currentNode.next = makeNode()
    currentNode = currentNode.next
  }
  return nodeList
}
console.log(makeNodeList(5))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Using `recursion`

```js
function makeNodeList(length) {
 if(length==0)return {};
 return {
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1,
    next: makeNodeList(length-1)
  };

}
console.log(makeNodeList(5))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```